# Deploying SSIS Project in SQL Server Management Studio 18.2

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2019

i am trying to deploy a SSIS project in SQL server Management Studio 18.2 (SQL server 2019). for that when i was trying to create a catalog (SSISDB) under integration services Catalog. SSMS is asking me to create SSIS IR, and while create SSIS IR, its asking to provide Azure Data Factory Subscription.
but i don't have subscription and i don't want too subscribe for Azure Data Factory. do i have to purchase subscription to create SSISDB in Sql Server 2019? or do we have alternate option like we had in previous versions of SSMS?
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i have to purchase subscription to create SSISDB in Sql Server
>   2019?

No, this is not required for on-premise use. The **SSIS IR** required if your company wants to host the SSIS catalog and execution environment into the cloud. Or, to be more precise, to ADF.

In your case, after entering the password, just click on <kbd>OK</kbd> instead of <kbd>Create SSIS IR</kbd> just like shown on a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alexander, when i was doing this i also tried to find out the OK button but it was not even showing me the OK button, sorry i missed to mention that in my question. then Now i installed SSMS 17.9.1 and created SSISDB in SSMS 17.9.1 and its done successfully. and now when start SSMS 18.2 its showing SSIDB there also. so i am good now. i will again uninstall SSMS 17.9.1

Comment: @RohitSharma, I think it can be related to the size of the wizards window. The OK and Cancel buttons perhaps just gone behind the bottom edge of your screen. The SSMS 17 has a smaller one for that wizard.

Comment: That make sense, Thanks for your help. appreciated.